# rgb to gray , image precessing in python

Tags: python, image

I started earlier to write a code that gathers various methods of image denoising. I had a problem with RGB images, though, so I tried instead to work on grayscale ones. I wrote a code to convert from rgb to gray as follows :

```
 def rgb_to_gray(image):
    from numpy import zeros
    a,b,c=image.shape
    h=zeros((a,b))
    for i in range(0,a):
      for j in range(0,b):
          h[i][j]=0.299*image[i][j][0]+0.587*image[i][j][1]+0.114*image[i][j][2]
    return h  

 e=imread('c:\..')
 m=rgb_to_gray(e)
 imshow(m)
 show()
```

I do not found the result I am expecting. When I change the code as follows :

```
image[i][j]=0.299*image[i][j][0]+0.587*image[i][j][1]+0.114*image[i][j][2]
.
.
return(image)
```

I get effectively a gray scale image,  I don't know why it's not working in the function.

Comment: What do you get using the first method?

Comment: Using the first method , the outcome is an image marked by yellow and green , well i've had  some problems with PyQt not to long ago but could it effectively influence the result ?